# SideNav overlaps everything

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two navigations. One sideNav and one navbar. The problem is that my sideNav overlaps everything. It's on top of the navbar and the footer. How can I move this under all of the layers? Here is an image to assist.. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z5Cm.jpg) I am using MVC with the navbar in my _layout.cshtml page, and the sidenav inside of my List.cshtml page.

SideNav

```
<!-- Sidebar navigation -->
        <div id="slide-out" class="side-nav sn-bg-1 fixed">
            <ul class="custom-scrollbar">
<!-- Side navigation links -->
                 <li>
                    <ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion">
                        <li>
                            <a class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r">
                                <i class="fas fa-hand-pointer"></i> Websites<i class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i>
                            </a>
                            <div class="collapsible-body">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                    <a class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r">
                                        <i class="fas fa-hand-pointer"></i> Sort By Category<i class="fas rotate-icon"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="waves-effect">For authors</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i> Marketing<i class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i></a>
                            <div class="collapsible-body">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="waves-effect">Introduction</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="waves-effect">Monthly meetings</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i> Contact me<i class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i></a>
                            <div class="collapsible-body">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="waves-effect">FAQ</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="waves-effect">Write a message</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="waves-effect">FAQ</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="waves-effect">Write a message</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="waves-effect">FAQ</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="waves-effect">Write a message</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="waves-effect">FAQ</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" class="waves-effect">Write a message</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <!--/. Side navigation links -->
        </ul>
            <li>
                <ul class="social">
                    <li><a href="#" class="icons-sm fb-ic"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"> </i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="icons-sm pin-ic"><i class="fab fa-pinterest"> </i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="icons-sm gplus-ic"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"> </i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="icons-sm tw-ic"><i class="fab fa-twitter"> </i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <div class="sidenav-bg mask-strong"></div>
        </div>
        <!--/. Sidebar navigation -->
```

navbar

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark scrolling-navbar" style="background-color: #4285f4">
            <a class="navbar-brand font-weight-bold" asp-controller="Product" asp-action="List" id="navpadding"><strong>FIVEMANGO</strong></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent-4"
                    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent-4" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent-4">
                @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item ml-3">
                            <a class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light dark-grey-text font-weight-bold" asp-controller="Cart" asp-action="Index">
                                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart blue-text"></i> Cart
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown ml-3">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-light dark-grey-text font-weight-bold"
                               id="navbarDropdownMenuLink-4" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <i class="fas fa-user blue-text"></i> Profile
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-cyan" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink-4">
                                @*<a class="dropdown-item waves-effect waves-light" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">Login</a>*@
                                <a class="dropdown-item waves-effect waves-light" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Index">View Orders</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item waves-effect waves-light" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout">Log out</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                }
                else
                {
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item ml-3">
                            <a class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light dark-grey-text font-weight-bold" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">
                                <i class="fas fa-registered blue-text"></i> Sign Up
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item ml-3">
                            <a class="nav-link waves-effect waves-light dark-grey-text font-weight-bold" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">
                                <i class="fas fa-user blue-text"></i> Login
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                }
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: could you, please, let us the code?

Comment: Sure, I included the sidenav and some of the _layout page

Comment: Problem in js side I think when close the side bar and at first the with of the side bar shoud be minimized

Comment: Could you explain what you mean @LDS

Comment: hi as per your question there are multi layers in the page .So it is displayed by z-index of the div . so in js side or css the z-index and visibility is changed with dynamic with properties .try to find out that code of changing